# Connecting DB without showing DB credentials in Android App

Tags: java, android, sql-server, android-studio

I am having trouble with how to have secure access to my database with my android App in MS SQL Server.
All I can see on youtube are those that put the password and other credentials of their database in the code which is not secure. Could anyone give me a suggestion on which web services I should use or paths I should learn to solve this security issue in app making?

Comment: public key file?

Comment: Don't directly connect your Android app to an SQL Server? Aside from the security issues most commonly people doing this try to use the jTDS package - which hasn't been updated for many years, will not likely ever see an update again, and doesn't even support "modern" features such as UTF-16 encoded strings via SQL Server's `nchar` and `nvarchar` data types. Consider placing a web service between your app and SQL Server that performs the CRUD operations on its behalf, and make the app authenticate with it using OAUTH2 with client_credentials (that you can encrypt and/or revoke) or similar.